# MySQL Left Join: if primary condition does not exist use backup condition return only one

Tags: mysql, join

I have seen variations of this question asked but either they didn't apply or I didn't understand the answer/s.

I have two tables one table with charges types with additional cost and one of charges. I want to join them to get the appropriate values. I want to join the tables where the charge is between the startDate and the endDate and on the types. If there is not a match I want it to choose the type -1 (same condition for dates). If there is not a match I don't want it to show up in the results.

I initially was was going to do a normal left join ordered by 'type' desc and then group by 'type' believing that it would only leave me with the first type but I read that MySQL advises against this because the group by can be unpredictable and not always return the first match.

Tables:

```
startDate | endDate  | type | addCost
--------------------------------------
2010-01-01 2010-12-31  1     100
2010-01-01 2010-12-31  2     200
2010-01-01 2010-12-31 -1      50
2011-01-01 2012-02-20  3     350
2011-01-01 2012-02-20  1     150
2011-01-01 2012-02-20 -1      75


chargeDate | type | cost
---------------------------
2010-10-01  1     10
2010-11-01  2     20
2010-12-01  4     40
2011-02-01  3     60
2011-03-01  2     25
2011-04-01  4     25
```

Desired Results:

```
chargeDate | type | cost | addCost
---------------------------------
2010-10-01  1     10     100
2010-11-01  2     20     200 
2010-12-01  4     40      50
2011-02-01  3     60     350
2011-03-01  2     25      75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a subquery where I am trying to join `charges` with `charges_types`. If the join doesn't succeed, `type` is `null` and with `coalesce` I set `type_c` as `-1`, otherwise I set it to `type`. Then I join this subquery with `charges_types` again, and on the join clause i use `type_c` instead of `type`:

```
select c.chargeDate, c.type, c.cost, ct.addCost
from
  (select
     charges.chargeDate,
     charges.type,
     coalesce(charges_types.type, -1) as type_c,
     charges.cost
   from
     charges left join charges_types
     on charges.chargeDate between charges_types.startDate and charges_types.endDate
       and charges.type = charges_types.type) c
  inner join charges_types ct
  on c.chargeDate between ct.startDate and ct.endDate
     and c.type_c = ct.type
```

Comment: This looks like it should work for me. I will try it out as soon as I can and update this question. Thank you for your quick reply.